# How to get All children in hierarchical list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, linq

I have a list of MenuItems, each MenuItem has a further list of MenuItems thereby creating hierarchical list

```
Public Class MenuItemViewModel

    Public Property MenuItems As New ObservableCollection(Of MenuItemViewModel)

End Class
```

Now, I need to have all objects of type MenuItemViewModel in a flatList.
I know I can do recursion to solve this but I was hoping if I can use LINQ to create a list like this.

I tried to do it with selectMany but it doesn't seem to work in my case

```
MenuItemViewModels.SelectMany(Of MenuItemViewModel)(Function(f) f.MenuItems)
```

as this will only return a list till one level

Can you please tell me if this is possible using LINQ or any other way ?

Thanks